# Broken Dnf update on centos 8

Tags: centos, update, centos8, dnf

I am getting the following error while doing a `dnf update` on a centos 8 server.
I have already tried the following:

> ```
> dnf clean all
> dnf distro-sync
> dnf update --best --allowerasing
> ```

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:15 ago on Sun 27 Dec 2020 09:00:12 AM EST.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package libgs-9.25-7.el8.x86_64
  - problem with installed package libgs-9.25-7.el8.x86_64
  - package libgs-9.25-7.el8.x86_64 requires libidn.so.11()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package libgs-9.25-7.el8.x86_64 requires libidn.so.11(LIBIDN_1.0)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libidn-1.34-5.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install both libidn-1.36-1.0.el8.x86_64 and libidn-1.34-5.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Edit:

I had to disable the `city-fan` as it was trying to update newer packages.I need the city-fan repo only for curl

Answer (score 1):

I eventually enable city-fan repo but allowed it to update only curl.The `/etc/yum.repos.d/city-fan.repo` should be as follows:

```
[CityFan]
name=City Fan Repo
baseurl=http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
includepkgs=curl*
exclude=*
```

I hope this helps someone.